# SonicWall : Blocking Access Between Different Subnets or Interfaces

Tags: subnet, sonicwall, interface

I have two interfaces on NSA 220 configured as follows

**Real interface X2**

192.168.1.1/24

LAN Zone

**Virtual interface X2:V1**

192.168.2.1/24

VLAN ID 100

LAN Zone

In this configuration computers in any of the subnets above can successfully reach each others, what I need to do is to block traffic between these two subnets?

How do I do this?

Comment: Look in [SonicOS 6.1 – Administration Guide Network > Zones](http://documents.software.dell.com/SonicOS/6.1/administration-guide/network/configuring-network-zones/network-zones?ParentProduct=631)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the LAN Zone has **Interface Trust** enabled, which means all interfaces within the same Zone trust each other (pass traffic). Go to **Network**, **Zones**, and *Edit the Zone* in question (LAN) and remove the checkmark from **Allow Interface Trust**. This will remove the auto-added LAN<->LAN Allow ANY/ANY/ANY rule.

Alternatively if these are NOT really both part of the same Zone (security context) then either change one of the interfaces *to a different Zone* (eg. DMZ) or create a new Zone. By default traffic between Zones is only allowed from "more trusted" to "less trusted" (but not the other way. Eg. from LAN to DMZ but not DMZ to LAN).

Answer (score 3):

By default, communication intra-zone is allowed. You just enter in Firewall->Access rules, select LAN->LAN and unmark the last rule wich allow intra-zone connections.

In my opinion, if you don't want communication at all, put X2 and X2:V1 in different zones.